# Retaining logs from Hadoop job after it's executed

Tags: hadoop

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to grab all the job logs / task attempt logs of a particular run, and persist them somewhere (HDFS, perhaps)?

I know that the logs are on the local filesystem at `/var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/userlogs` for any particular job's task attempts, and that I could write a script to SSH to each of the slave nodes and scoop them all up.  However, I'm trying to avoid that if it makes sense to - perhaps there's some built-in function of Hadoop that I'm not aware of?

I did find [this link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/), which is old, but contains some helpful information -- but did not include the answer I'm looking for.

`mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours` is set to 24 by default, so any job's logs will be automatically purged after 1 day.  Is there anything I can do besides increasing the value of the `retain.hours` parameter to get these to persist?

Comment: Use flume agent to aggregate the log. But it is again depending on how many jobs you have and other factors. If it is only a handful of jobs, i would go with @Donald Miner answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything out of the box that exists, but I have done something similar manually.

We set up cron jobs that run every 20 minutes that look for new logs for task attempts, then pumps them all into HDFS into a specific directory. We modified the files names so that the hostname it is coming from is appended. Then, we had MapReduce jobs try to find issues, calculate stats like runtimes, etc. It was pretty neat. We did something similar with NameNode logs, too.